# variable substitution in variable name

Tags: perl

i have hundreds of lines like this one where only the variable name changes (they all have the same values)

```
# no change required here
my $worksheet_stats      = $workbook->add_worksheet('Stats');
my $worksheet_blockleave = $workbook->add_worksheet('Block Leave ');
my $worksheet_disabled   = $workbook->add_worksheet('Disabled Users');
my $worksheet_past       = $workbook->add_worksheet('EX Users');

# dirty (what i want to simplify without having to touch at the rest of the code as the script is huge)
$worksheet_blockleave->write( 0, 0, "GPN" );
$worksheet_blockleave->write( 0, 1, "Firstname" );
$worksheet_blockleave->write( 0, 2, "Lastname" );
$worksheet_blockleave->set_column( 0, 1, 30 );
$worksheet_blockleave->set_column( 0, 2, 30 );
$worksheet_disabled->write( 0, 0, "GPN" );
$worksheet_disabled->write( 0, 1, "Firstname" );
$worksheet_disabled->write( 0, 2, "Lastname" );
$worksheet_disabled->set_column( 0, 1, 30 );
$worksheet_disabled->set_column( 0, 2, 30 );
$worksheet_past->write( 0, 0, "GPN" );
$worksheet_past->write( 0, 1, "Firstname" );
$worksheet_past->write( 0, 2, "Lastname" );
$worksheet_past->set_column( 0, 1, 30 );
$worksheet_past->set_column( 0, 2, 30 );
...

# doing other stuff with these variables later (that i don't want to change)
$worksheet_blockleave->write( blabla, 0, blabla );
....
```

is there a way create a loop that applies the setup to all of these things by not having to mention the whole variable name ? (to simplify the code and reduce it)

something like (not tried, i believe it won't work):

```
foreach ("blockleave", "disabled", "past", "xxx", ...... )
{
    $worksheet_${_}->write( 0, 0, "GPN" );
    $worksheet_${_}-->write( 0, 1, "Firstname" );
    $worksheet_${_}-->write( 0, 2, "Lastname" );
    $worksheet_${_}-->set_column( 0, 1, 30 );
    $worksheet_${_}-->set_column( 0, 2, 30 );
}
```

in fact this is working :

```
foreach ($worksheet_blockleave,$worksheet_disabled,$worksheet_past,$worksheet_future,$worksheet_t2,$worksheet_t4,$worksheet_t24,$worksheet_enabled,$worksheet_VR,$worksheet_USBW,$worksheet_USBR,$worksheet_P08,$worksheet_ZH) {
   $_->write( 0, 0, "GPN" );
   $_->write( 0, 1, "Firstname" );
   $_->write( 0, 2, "Lastname" );
   $_->set_column( 0, 1, 30 );
   $_->set_column( 0, 2, 30 );
}
```

but i was expecting to have a shorter solution where i wouldn't have to specify the $worksheet_ prefix to save some space and clarify the script a bit..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

[Don't use a variable variable name](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html). You could use a hash.

```perl
for (qw( blockleave disabled past ... )) {
    my $worksheet = $worksheets{$_};
    $worksheet->write( 0, 0, "GPN" );
    $worksheet->write( 0, 1, "Firstname" );
    $worksheet->write( 0, 2, "Lastname" );
    $worksheet->set_column( 0, 1, 30 );
    $worksheet->set_column( 0, 2, 30 );
}
```

Comment: interesting, but it doesn't work :( i edited my initial post to show how i define these variables.

Comment: It does work. Did you use a hash?